# How do I unit test a Ruby app for return codes

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm not terribly familiar with Ruby testing and my searches haven't yielded an answer to my specific question.

Currently, I have an app that raises StandardError to exit on certain conditions. The drawback to this is that the exit code is always 1.

I want to use exit() to provide unique codes to the exit conditions.

Currently, the project spec tests the StandardError mechanism as follows:

```
it "should raise an exception if no unignored project coverage file files were found" do
  fixtures_project.ignore_list = ["*fixturesTests*", "*fixtures*"]
  expect {fixtures_project.coverage_files}.to raise_error(StandardError)
end
```

I want to do something like `assert($?.exit == 102)`, but I still need the fixtures_project.coverage_files to fire before hand in order to get the exit code.

I've tried variations of `assert_equal(102, fixtures_project.coverage_files, "Hello there")` inside the it/end with no luck. I'm sure this is probably simple Ruby, but I haven't [grokked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) this bit yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right in trying to use `$?` object. Just call `$?.exitstatus` to get your exit status.

```
it "should raise an exception if no unignored project coverage file files were found" do
  fixtures_project.ignore_list = ["*fixturesTests*", "*fixtures*"]
  expect {fixtures_project.coverage_files}.to raise_error(StandardError)
  expect($?.exitstatus).to eq(102)
end
```

Comment: How would I do this without checking for the raise_error. IE., how do I call fixtures_project.coverage_files to generate the exit code? I've removed the "raise" in the code, so I can't test for that anymore.

Comment: Why don't you want to have raise_error expectation in there as well? Otherwise, you'll have to call the method and rescue the exception, which is not a good practice in a spec.

Comment: In the code under test, if I raise StandardError before I exit(nnn), then the app exits with code 1, rather than the code I want. Then the second expect fails in the unit test. If I exit(nnn) before raising StandardError, then the first expect fails in the test.